# How to fix TextFormField cause rebuild widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I've got the same issue at [#9280](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9282). I tried all solutions from that topic with/without GlobalKey for Scaffold and Form but the problem wasn't fixed.
I tried to build a authentication form with login and signup. But the keyboard doesn't show when I tap the TextFormField at the first time. Then I try to input some letter from physical keyboard, the widget is rebuilt. Like this:
[login screen](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/27873503/50627535-6bbadd00-0f66-11e9-93b3-7ec5be87eb11.gif)

Nothing to be log when I run flutter run --verbose, so I logged manually. Every tapping on field, the widget called dispose -> init -> build.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.195], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.0.0 at D:\flutter
    • Framework revision 5391447fae (5 weeks ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
    • Engine revision 7375a0f414
    • Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\PeterHo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 29.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.30.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 2.21.1

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:successhunter/style/theme.dart' as Theme;
import 'package:successhunter/utils/helper.dart' as Helper;

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  // Variable
  double screenWidth;
  double screenHeight;

  PageController _pageController;

  // Business
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  // Layout
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        alignment: AlignmentDirectional.topCenter,
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildHeaderSection(context),
          _buildAuthSection(context),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildHeaderSection(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: <Widget>[
        Stack(
          alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Helper.buildHeaderBackground(context),
            Text(
              'Success Hunter',
              style: Theme.header1Style.copyWith(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 30.0,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildAuthSection(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          height: screenHeight * 0.25,
        ),
        Container(
          height: screenHeight * 0.73,
          width: screenWidth - 20.0,
          child: Card(
            elevation: 10.0,
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            ),
            child: _buildAuthPageView(context),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildAuthPageView(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView(
      controller: _pageController,
      children: <Widget>[
        _buildLoginView(context),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildLoginView(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
              'LOGIN',
              style: Theme.header2Style.copyWith(
                color: Theme.Colors.mainColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'someone@email.com',
                  labelText: 'Email',
                  labelStyle: Theme.contentStyle.copyWith(
                    color: Theme.Colors.thirdColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Password',
                  labelStyle: Theme.contentStyle.copyWith(
                    color: Theme.Colors.thirdColor,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried Your `_buildAuthPageView` Code. Works Fine. - Try : To set - `targetSdkVersion 27` in your - `android/app/build.gradle` file instead of `28`.

Comment: Bottom Overflow Error is there in your Code as your Parent Widget is Stack - Try to use Scroll able Widget like `ListView`.

Comment: Hey, have you found any solution to this or what is causing the bug? I have similar behavior using a Form inside a TabBarView